What associated DLL's need to be included for the release of a .NET 6.0 console app?
I have written a console app in Microsoft Visual Studio and compiled using the "Batch Build" command. I have placed this executable into its own folder as I am told from a tutorial to do so that it can run as a task from the Windows 10 "Task Scheduler". It works. I mean, it seems to run from my computer.
My IT guy wants it to be run off the server at the company. So he showed me how to download the settings from the "Task Scheduler".  This file is an .XML file.
I have shared the folder that has the .EXE and .XML files with him and he has recently come back to tell me that when he tried to run this program from the command line (it is a console app, by the way), he got an error message stating that there were .DLL's missing.
What associated DLL's need to be included for the release of a .NET 6.0 console app? I went into the directory where Microsoft Visual Studio built the release version of the executable and I see a lot of .DLL's. Which ones should be used by being moved to the folder. Is there another way I could do this? Please advise.
Here is the list of files in the Release folder (what a huge list!  Surely, they can not all be required !):
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is C292-BE2E

 Directory of C:\source\repos\SharePointListCreation\bin\Release\net6.0

09/26/2024  09:29 AM    <DIR>          .
09/26/2024  09:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/15/2023  05:45 PM           406,528 AngleSharp.Css.dll
05/31/2022  01:44 PM           882,176 AngleSharp.dll
07/26/2021  06:36 PM           378,744 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll
11/12/2018  12:30 PM            22,904 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
11/12/2018  12:30 PM            15,224 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
11/12/2018  12:29 PM            76,152 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
11/12/2018  12:29 PM            38,776 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll
11/12/2018  12:28 PM            32,120 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll
11/12/2018  12:37 PM            70,520 Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll
10/22/2021  06:47 PM            27,264 Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
01/14/2022  02:54 PM            38,504 Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
10/22/2021  06:47 PM            25,216 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
10/22/2021  06:48 PM            43,632 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
09/26/2022  12:42 PM            82,560 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
11/10/2018  07:26 PM            17,976 Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
11/12/2018  12:30 PM            22,904 Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
10/22/2021  06:50 PM            68,736 Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll
10/22/2021  06:51 PM            62,064 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
10/22/2021  06:50 PM            44,656 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
10/22/2021  06:50 PM            59,008 Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
10/22/2021  06:51 PM            40,048 Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
11/12/2018  12:28 PM            19,832 Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll
03/25/2021  06:18 PM           142,224 Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
05/20/2021  05:05 PM         8,584,592 Microsoft.Graph.dll
06/06/2024  05:09 PM         1,005,600 Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
06/06/2024  05:14 PM            66,592 Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll
08/21/2024  11:16 PM            20,000 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll
08/21/2024  11:16 PM           155,160 Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
08/21/2024  11:16 PM            36,896 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
08/21/2024  11:16 PM           337,432 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
11/12/2018  12:28 PM            74,616 Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           101,056 Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM            41,720 Microsoft.Office.Client.TranslationServices.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           108,120 Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           528,520 Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           416,536 Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM         1,493,144 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM            50,920 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           168,680 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           200,888 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM            30,408 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Applications.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           138,816 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM            92,432 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM           181,968 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll
08/20/2024  02:34 PM            54,416 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll
10/22/2021  06:40 PM            26,224 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
03/17/2021  03:03 PM           695,336 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
09/26/2024  09:29 AM                 0 output.txt
08/16/2024  06:24 AM         2,518,448 PnP.Core.dll
08/16/2024  06:41 AM        11,162,672 PnP.Framework.dll
10/29/2020  06:07 AM           259,072 Portable.Xaml.dll
09/24/2024  11:26 AM    <DIR>          runtimes
09/25/2024  08:14 PM            96,506 SharePointListCreation.deps.json
09/25/2024  08:14 PM            81,920 SharePointListCreation.dll
09/25/2024  08:14 PM           151,040 SharePointListCreation.exe
09/25/2024  08:14 PM            35,328 SharePointListCreation.pdb
09/25/2024  08:14 PM               253 SharePointListCreation.runtimeconfig.json
08/19/2022  02:58 PM           396,424 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
02/15/2023  07:32 PM           145,072 System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
10/22/2021  06:51 PM           130,664 System.DirectoryServices.dll
10/22/2021  06:49 PM           175,216 System.Drawing.Common.dll
08/21/2024  11:16 PM            90,168 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
10/22/2021  06:49 PM           122,480 System.IO.Packaging.dll
10/22/2021  06:51 PM            20,592 System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll
10/22/2021  06:49 PM           104,048 System.Security.Permissions.dll
10/23/2022  12:54 PM           457,856 System.Text.Json.dll
10/22/2021  06:49 PM            25,712 System.Windows.Extensions.dll
02/12/2023  03:28 PM            33,792 TimeZoneConverter.dll
              67 File(s)     33,235,103 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  702,420,926,464 bytes free


Simply use the publishing feature?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

The dependencies depend on what you need for your code. We can't know what libraries you use.

If you want to simplify it, you can use Fody Costura to bundle all the DLLs into the exe https://github.com/Fody/Costura

THe answer is that one has to publish the app in order to have all the proper files accompany the solution.
